# How could I set an activity to be the one to be resumed (by multitask)

Tags: android, android-intent

I am experiencing a little pain on Android. I have two activities, one is a Splash Screen, launched when you click on the app icon, and an other one which can wake up when a specific event occurred (a NFC event, but it is not the problem).

There is the declaration in the manifest :

```
<activity android:label="@string/general.appName"    android:name=".activity.SplashActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
<activity android:excludeFromRecents="true" android:label="@string/general.appName" android:name=".EventReceiver" android:noHistory="true" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TRANSACTION_DETECTED">
            </action>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT">
            </category>

            <data android:host="secure" android:path="/aXXXXX" android:port="0" android:scheme="nfc"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

All works fine, it means that the EventReceiver is launched when it received a specific event, the Splash Screen is functional etc...
But, when the application is launched by an event, so it is the EventReceiver which is launched first. If I pause the app by clicking on the home button of the phone, and by long clicking on it again, it makes appear the multitask table, with all the recent opened apps. There, is I click on my application, it resumed the application on the EventReceiver, just like if an event had occurred. So do you know a way to resume an application on one selected activity only (in my case the SplashScreen).
Or do you know a way to recognize that the application was resumed by a multitask function ? (I could open the good activity at the onCreate of my EventReceiver too if I get this information).

For the moment, the only solution I found is to put a android:excludeFromRecents="true" flag on my EventReceiver activity. This will result that the application will not appear in the multitask table if the application was launched by an event. But this is a little bit tricky and I do not like that very much.

Do you have any ideas ?

Thank you very much beforehand for your answers ! (and sorry for my scholar English ^^)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really have to detect when the application is lauched from the "recents" you can use intent flags.

```
 if (getIntent().getFlags() & Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY) {
     // Lauched from recent apps.
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly in my case, just by using your code and : 
    if ((getIntent().getFlags() & Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY) != 0) {
       startActivity(new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class));
       finish();
  }

Answer (score 0):

Do NOT use a splash screen. It only slows down your app experience and has no value what so ever.

In addition... Android apps are a lose set of activities... There is no concrete entry point that would need a splash screen.

That said... the app switcher returns you to the previously active activity. In your case the .EventReceiver. You could change your structure by using a second activity that shows your ui so that the EventReceiver lets you forward to that.

Correct me if i am mistaken... But can't you intercept the nfc event with an receiver? From there you should open your ui activity.

Comment: For the SplashScreen, it is not me who wants it, I have some obligations ^^
But it is not the matter, I could say the HomeActivity is the one that I want to be resumed.
In fact when I resume with multitask, it is like the Android system registered the Event itself, and I receive it again, so my EventReceiver is launched.
The reading of the event is a little bit long (1-2seconds), this is why I have this EventReceiver. If I opened an activity before it, it will be the same problem here I think :(